# What is a good FAT file system for ARM7-TDMI

Tags: embedded, filesystems, arm, fat32

I'm using the ARM7TDMI-S (NXP processor) and I need a file system capable of reading/writing to an SD card.  There are so many available, what have people used and been happy with?  One that requires the least amount of setup is best - so the less I have to do to get it started (i.e. write device drivers to NXP's hardware) the better.

I am currently using CMX's RTOS as the OS for this project.

Comment: What operating system are you using? ("None" is a valid answer.)

Comment: Added RTOS information to question

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use either [EFSL](http://efsl.be/) or [Chan's FAT File System Module](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html).  I have used both on MMC/SC cards without problems. The choice between them may come down to the license terms and pre-existing ports to your target.  Martin Thomas's [ARM Projects](http://www.siwawi.arubi.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/) site has examples for both libraries.

Answer (score 1):

[FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) is popular precisely *because* it's so simple. The main problems with FAT are performance (because of its simplicity, it's not very fast) and its limited size (2GB for FAT16, though 2TB for FAT32)

Comment: As an added bonus, SD cards come preformatted to FAT or FAT32 depending on size.

Comment: Another problem with FAT is that it's rather fragile. Then again, because of its simplicity, it's also generally easy to recover data from a mucked up volume.

Comment: Note that long file-name support on FAT32 is subject to licensing.  You have to pay a royalty to Microsoft to use LFN: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Licensing.  Be aware if you are creating a commercial product - their lawyers are probably bigger and smarter than yours.